# "Refresh" icon for ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, image, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use the wonderful library by Jake; ActionbarSherlock(ABS) version 4.2. I need to use the refresh icon in the actionbar for refreshing the content of the SherlockListFragment.

I have got the code right but I could not find the right icon the refresh button. *"Search"* and other icons are build right into ABS. For example `.setIcon(R.drawable.abs_ic_search)`.

I tried and  downloaded a few from the google images but they have some or other problem like this one has a white background.

[image]

**My Question**

How can get icon for *"refresh"* which can be used in Actionbar with Actionbar Sherlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are readily available in the Action Bar Icon Pack, found [on the Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. I used Android Asset Studio for it.
Here is the [link](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res/clipart/icons/navigation_refresh.svg&name=refresh&theme=light).

Basically it helps at the time of creating your own icons. They also have the stock Action Bar icons.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is one amazing thing "Android Asset Studio".

Answer (score 1):

Eric is right, but you don't have to download it once again. you can just find all the icons of android sdk here on your PC(if window):

android-sdk\platforms\android-"VERSION"\data\res\drawable-"DPI"

the name is  "ic_menu_refresh.png" for refresh icon